# GitHub OAuth logout or revoke of token

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, github-api, logout

To authenticate a user with a *GitHub* App we only need to do two requests to the `login` api:

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
```

Now that we have used the `token`, how do we revoke it to logout the user?