# Revoke GitHub OAuth token

Tags: github, oauth, github-actions, github-oauth

I made user authorizztion via GitHub OAuth. So now I'm trying to make a log out func. According to GitHub I can do it via revoking access token (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/apps#delete-an-app-authorization). But this endpoint throws 404 all the time and according to the API main page (https://api.github.com/) there is no such endpoint at all. Found similar questions but without solutions.

- [Remove/revoke GitHub OAuth 'access_token'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230534/remove-revoke-github-oauth-access-token)
- [GitHub OAuth logout or revoke of token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626219/github-oauth-logout-or-revoke-of-token)

Comment: Since you want to do a logout function, i guess the user logged in before? So he made an authentication? Wouldn't it be enough just to kill the session for a logout? Revoking the whole app from Github seems a bit overkill. This way, every time a user wants to log in, they need to give consent.

Comment: Tried this approach(session.clear) - but it gives nothing, looks like I didn't take into account something.